# Getting error in parsing nested dictionary: Platform and sha256

Tags: python, json, key

Getting platform and sha256 key error while extracting `classification` and `query hash` value. Can someone identify what I am doing wrong here? I am able to extract other values except those two.

I'm doing it like this:

```py
artifact_item=dict()
artifact_item['classification']=artifacts.get('classification',{})
artifact_item['query_hash']=artifacts.get('query_hash',{})
```

The artifacts:

```py
artifacts={{
    "status": "SUSPICIOUS",
    "scanner_count": 48,
    "classification": {
        "platform": "Win32",
        "type": "Malware",
        "family_name": "Xls"
    },
    "scanner_match": 4,
    "threat_name": "Win32.Malware.Xls",
    "query_hash": {
        "sha256": "de5aae888888888c81bf2b6be27a3e68ef8db4bbeb378a9fff36601d112d435f"
    }
    
},
{
    "status": "UNKNOWN",
    "scanner_count": 0,
    "classification": {},
    "scanner_match": 0,
    "threat_name": "",
    "query_hash": {
        "sha256": "2fa54155787a9f070b6ae93ea267fc759b3261fd00000ca166c5c30a1f1bae12"
    }
},
{
    "status": "UNKNOWN",
    "scanner_count": 0,
    "classification": {},
    "scanner_match": 0,
    "threat_name": "",
    "query_hash": {
        "sha256": "a9fcd0c850d5d77160d58e0000760bcef221279d0f78c0460fbbb4269cb8c4a5"
    }
},
{
    "status": "KNOWN",
    "scanner_count": 40,
    "classification": {},
    "scanner_match": 0,
    "threat_name": "",
    "query_hash": {
        "sha256": "e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c0000fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855"
    }
    
}}
```

Comment: Where are you getting your JSON data from? is it a file you've built?

Comment: yeah its a file ..havent included that code here

Answer (score 1):

After trying to replicate your error I've noticed that the artifacts object (that in my understanding is a JSON data object?) is formatted incorrectly,
to fix this, I took the artifact json data and gave each dictionary a parameter like so:

```
{
    "Property1" : {
        "status": "SUSPICIOUS",
        "scanner_count": 48,
        "classification": {
            "platform": "Win32",
            "type": "Malware",
            "family_name": "Xls"
        },
        "scanner_match": 4,
        "threat_name": "Win32.Malware.Xls",
        "query_hash": {
            "sha256": "de5aae888888888c81bf2b6be27a3e68ef8db4bbeb378a9fff36601d112d435f"
        }
        
    },
    "Property2" :{
        "status": "UNKNOWN",
        "scanner_count": 0,
        "classification": {},
        "scanner_match": 0,
        "threat_name": "",
        "query_hash": {
            "sha256": "2fa54155787a9f070b6ae93ea267fc759b3261fd00000ca166c5c30a1f1bae12"
        }
    },
    "Property3" :{
        "status": "UNKNOWN",
        "scanner_count": 0,
        "classification": {},
        "scanner_match": 0,
        "threat_name": "",
        "query_hash": {
            "sha256": "a9fcd0c850d5d77160d58e0000760bcef221279d0f78c0460fbbb4269cb8c4a5"
        }
    },
    "Property4" :{
        "status": "KNOWN",
        "scanner_count": 40,
        "classification": {},
        "scanner_match": 0,
        "threat_name": "",
        "query_hash": {
            "sha256": "e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c0000fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855"
        }
        
    }
}
```

notice the `"Property1"` key value that comes for each dictionary,
then by importing the JSON library in python we can load and parse the data and use it to obtain our data:

EDITED:

```
import json 
  
# Opening JSON file 
with open('data.json') as json_file: 
    data = json.load(json_file) 
  
    # Print the type of data variable 
    artifact_item = dict(data['Property1'])
    classification = artifact_item.get('classification',{})
    if classification == {}:
        print('Classification is empty')
    else:
        plat = classification['platform']
```

we can iterate on each `Property` key value in the JSON to obtain all our data,
and of course we can use `artifact_item.get('classification',{})` to obtain the data you wanted.

EDIT: we can achieve the same property by doing:

```
artifact_item2 = dict(data['Property1'])['classification']['platform']
```

notice that I'm first creating a dictionary from the JSON data using `dict(data['Property1'])` and then accessing the data like a regular dictionary.

I hope this helped!

Comment: Hi, artifact_item=type(data['property'] ) you meant ryt ? Also I did that way only..but it's throwing key error for platform key :(

Comment: hey again, in order to get to the platform data you'll need to dive deeper into the JSON data, meaning - after we set `artifact_item` to the 'Property1' we can then get the classification and then the platform, I have updated my example to show you what I mean, hope it helps, thumbs up if it does!